# How can I get 'mobile-breakpoint' state enabled, in vuefity?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to control the `<v-navigation-drawer>` by `mobile-breakpoint` status.
When it is enabling, use to `drawer` else to `mini`.
How can I refer the `mobile-breakpoint` status?

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    
    <v-navigation-drawer
        v-model="drawer"
        :mini-variant.sync="mini"
        mobile-breakpoint="960"
        app>
      <h1>v-navigation-drawer</h1>
    </v-navigation-drawer>

    <v-btn @click="click"> Button </v-btn>
    
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "foo",
  data: () => ({
    drawer: true,
    mini: true
  }),
  methods: {
    click() {
      // How to refer 'mobile-breakpoint' status??
      if (mobileBreakpointEnabled) {
        this.drawer = !this.drawer
      } else {
        this.mini = !this.mini
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `this.$vuetify.breakpoint.mobile`

Comment: thanks. now i can refer from `this.$vuetify.breakpoint.width` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value is gonna be hardcoded and not changed, I would recommend to just use a computed to check if the breakpoint is reached.

You can use:

`this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name`

to see if you have reached your breakpoint.

Perhaps just having a breakpoint variable with the width you want to break it at is helpful to have.

See documentation:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/breakpoints/#breakpoint-service